How to show that the Gaussian sequence satisfies the sifting property of the delta function?
I am trying to show that the Gaussian sequence of functions, defined by
$g_a (x) = (\frac{1}{a\sqrt{\pi}}) e^\frac{-(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}$ satisfies the sifting property of the $\delta$ - function, namely the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g_a(x-x_0)f(x) \,dx\ = f(x_0)$ as ${a\to 0}$ ?
I have tried integrating by parts, taylor expanding around x_0 for various combinations of the integrand and integrating term by term, I have also tried breaking the integral into multiple regions but nothing seems to work.

Maybe start by working with $\int (f(x) - f(0))g_a(x), dx$ as $a\to 0$.

Have you tried looking at what happens for the Fourier transform?

Make a substitution so that you get $e^{-t^2}.$ Then use Dominated Convergence Theorem.
